# How to make Parse.File url's private?

Tags: parse-platform, google-cloud-storage, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have small app which has a feed section where user can post the data with images and can set post visibility to either public or followers only. For this, I am having Parse Server configured on Heroku with mLab resource and using GCS adapter (Google Cloud Storage) to store images and files. I have written `Parse Cloud Function` which returns the posts in json format with image or file url, and then I am showing the response in Android App. If there is image attached to post, I am using `Glide` library to show it using URL returned in the response.

Now my problem is, image's url returned from Parse Server is **public**, and hence anyone can access it from any where and can view the image.

So my question is, how to make parse file url private and can only be accessible by authenticated users only and no one will have access to image only using URL?

Comment: If I am not understanding wrong, could you confirm if your concern is to make files private in Google Cloud Storage? If yes, please have a look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405882/8791788). In Google Cloud Storage, you can make a bucket private or to only give access to user you want and in this way all the files inside that bucket will be only accessible by the users you give permission to, but if you don' want to make your bucket private, you can make the objects (files) private and only the users you mention will access to that object.

Comment: Please let me know if this was you concern.

Comment: Thanks @NibrassH, my bucket on GCS is already private, and hence the all urls of objects are also private (Default Uniform permissions) and no one is able hit it publicly, but when I am using parse-server-gcs-adapter and pull out the url using Parse.File object then that url is accessible from everywhere. So I want to make sure here that Parse.File url should be private and only accessible to authenticated users. Hope this will clear your convern.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have a private bucket and if you try to access the object link for any of the files, you are getting an access denied response. But if you try to access the file by using the `Parse.File` method from `parse-server-gcs-adapter`, the file is loaded. So your concern is why the file is being loaded since it is private ?

Comment: Yes perfectly right. Now I want it should be loaded using ```Parse.File``` method only if user is authenticated. If user isn't authenticated and try to hit that url from outside (from browser or anywhere), then he should get an access denied response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the parse-server-gcs-adapter [github link](https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-server-gcs-adapter) . It is stated that you can connect using `parse-server` configuration or `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Since you are having access to the files this means that you have successfully configured one of the above(make bucket private or objects private) methods. I can see that both of the configurations above will give you authenticated access to the bucket. Otherwise, you would have received an access denied error.

Therefore, if you try to access any of the files’ URLs from the web or incognito window and you get an access denied error response, but you can do so from `Parse.File` method, this means that your files are indeed protected from the web and the requests from the `Parse.File` method are authenticated from the configuration that you have setup.

Comment: Thanks @Nibrass. I didn't get the part **this means that your files are indeed protected from the web and the requests from the Parse.File method are authenticated from the configuration that you have setup**. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Reading the the github link, it says below that you have to provide project id, bucket id, app id etc. You can also set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which is used for authentication, so that's why when using Parse-server you can access the files in the bucket because you are authenticating to the bucket providing the previous information. And when I say it's protected from the web, it means, that nobody who is not authenticating can't see or acess your files.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but in my case the URLs got from ```Parse.File``` are getting accessed from any where even if user isn't authenticated and can directly hit it from incognito window as well. This is happening only in case if url is taken from ```Parse.File``` but not if url is directly taken from ```Google Cloud Storage```, GCS's URL shows access denied. So here I want Parse.File url to be work the same way as GCS's

Comment: Any suggestions/help on the above comment please @Nibrass?

Comment: I think for this you will need to set up a private parse server, as by Cloud Storage you are only accessing it privately.

Comment: Yes I do have private parse server but they aren't offering these kind of setup, but no problem thanks for your help, I will try to get some help from parse community :)